# How to copy a Julia DataFrame in a threaded loop?

Tags: multithreading, loops, dataframe, julia

I've got the following problem :

A DataFrame named cr1 with 553 columns

Then, I make two loops as follow :

```
cr2=copy(cr1)

   #-----------------#
   #Loop on scenarios#
   #-----------------#
    @threads for k in 0:499
        cr1=copy(cr2)
        cr1[!,"scn"].=k

        cr1 = leftjoin(cr1,tra,on = [:scn])

        for i in 1:40
            #----------------------#
            ##Projection on 40 years
            #----------------------#
            cr1[!,"ch_prime"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"ch_prime"].*(cr1[!,"coll_"*str(i)]
            ...job on other columns
```

At the beginning, I make a copy of cr1 to keep the vision of the DataFrame at this stage. Indeed I need to restart of this vision at each iteration of the k-loop.
Then I consider the scenario = k to make the right join with the DF called tra with 40 columns (tra1 to tra40) and k lines.
Finally, I make another loop to project all my variables on 4O years.

But it doesn't work. Julia do some job but cr1 is not modified.

I tried adding a global on the first line of the loop and squeezing the @threads

```
for k in 0:499
        global cr1=copy(cr2)
```

Then it works, but with no threading and I want to keep it for performance

Have you any idea another way to do this or a way to thread the last solution ?

*EDIT*

Here is the full code (a bit long sorry), if it could help:

```
#Définit la fonction string avec une syntaxe plus courte
#Permet de conserver le code Python
function str(x)
    string(x)
end


# %% Début du programme
@time begin
    ##+ Import des tables
    donnee=CSV.File("/Users/Python/Python_VIF_sto/donnee.csv")|> DataFrame!
    lapse=CSV.File("/Users/Python/Python_VIF_sto/lapse.csv")|> DataFrame!
    dc=CSV.File("/Users/Python/Python_VIF_sto/dc.csv")|> DataFrame!
    ind_action=CSV.File("/Users/Python/Python_VIF_sto/ind_action.csv")|> DataFrame!
    tra=CSV.File("/Users/Python/Python_VIF_sto/tra.csv")|> DataFrame!
    ts=CSV.File("/Users/Python/Python_VIF_sto/ts.csv")|> DataFrame!
    ech=CSV.File("/Users/Python/Python_VIF_sto/ech.csv")|> DataFrame!
    sw=CSV.File("/Users/Python/Python_VIF_sto/sw.csv")|> DataFrame!
    df=CSV.File("/Users/Python/Python_VIF_sto/df.csv")|> DataFrame!
    tx_is=CSV.File("/Users/Python/Python_VIF_sto/tx_is.csv")|> DataFrame!
    fga=CSV.File("/Users/Python/Python_VIF_sto/fga.csv")|> DataFrame!
    fgp=CSV.File("/Users/Python/Python_VIF_sto/fgp.csv")|> DataFrame!
    fgacq=CSV.File("/Users/Python/Python_VIF_sto/fgacq.csv")|> DataFrame!
    inf=CSV.File("/Users/Python/Python_VIF_sto/inf.csv")|> DataFrame!

    #Definition des parametres communs
    ppb0=1347911164;     # PPB initiale
    const global dur_proj=40;         # Durée de projection
    nb_coll=6;           # 6 années de collecte possible
    tcomp_mod=0         # Mode de determination composante technique PB min (1=fixe ou 0=libre)
    tcomp_fixe=1        # Composante si fixe (1=prev 0=RT)
    fdc=1               # 1 = frontiere des contrats S2 / 0 = désactivée

    #CR initial avec les paramètres en t=0#
    cr1=copy(donnee)
    cr1[!, :annee].= 1
    cr1[!, :der_fg].=0.01  #Dérive des frais au delà inflation


    #Creation des dummies#
    cr1[!,:eu] .= (cr1.supp.=="eu")
    cr1[!,:uc] .= (cr1.supp.=="uc")
    cr1[!, :prev] .= (cr1.supp.=="prev")
    cr1[!, :ve] .= (cr1.supp.=="ve")


    #Construction des taux projetés sur horizon de projection(rachats, décès, indices..)#

    #Deces - par produit#
    cr1 = leftjoin(cr1,dc, on =[:age, :tab_dc,:ab_dc]) # Décès
    #----------------------#
    #Echeances & Arbitrages#
    #----------------------#

    cr1 = leftjoin(cr1,ech, on =[:tab_ech])   #Echeances
    cr1 = leftjoin(cr1,sw, on =[:tab_sw])     #Arbitrages

    #---------------------------#
    #Frais admin / acq / prestas#
    #---------------------------#
    cr1 = leftjoin(cr1,fga, on =[:fg_ad])     #Frais d"administration
    cr1 = leftjoin(cr1,fgp, on =[:fg_prest])  #Frais sur prestations
    cr1 = leftjoin(cr1,fgacq,on =[:fg_acq])  #Frais d"acquisition

    #------------#
    #---Lapses---#
    #------------#
    cr1 = leftjoin(cr1,lapse,on = [:tab_lapse]) #Rachats - vision simple - pas de gestion de la collecte

    m = Matrix(cr1[!,columnindex(cr1, :anc1):columnindex(cr1, :anc100)])
    v = cr1.anc
    insertcols!(cr1, ["lap$k" => getindex.(Ref(m), axes(cr1, 1), v .+ k .- 1) for k in 1:dur_proj]...)

    #--------#
    #Collecte#
    #--------#
    # On force la collecte à zero au dela du plan
    for i in 7:dur_proj
        cr1[!,"coll_"*str(i)].=0
    end

    # Collecte prevoyance
    for i in 1:dur_proj
        cr1[!,"ca_prev"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"ca_prev"*str(i-1)].*(1 .-cr1[!,"lap"*str(i)])
        .+cr1[!,"coll_"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"prev"]
    end

    # Application de la frontière des contrats au delà de la première année
    for i in 2:dur_proj
        cr1[!,"ca_prev"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"ca_prev"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"fdc"]
    end

    #------------------------------------------#
    #Allocation PPB ini aux prorata des PM Euro#
    #------------------------------------------#

    s=(cr1[!,"eu"].+cr1[!,"ve"]).*cr1[!,"pm_0"]
    som=max(1,sum(s))                                                                      #Eviter les divisions par zero qd pas de produits euros
    ratio=s/som
    cr1[!,"ppb0"].=ppb0.*ratio                                                                  #Quid de la prev


    cr2=copy(cr1)

   #------------------------#
    #Boucle sur les scenarios#
    #------------------------#
    @threads for k in 0:499
        global cr1=copy(cr2)
        cr1[!,"scn"].=k   #scenario deterministe / parametrable en sto

        #---------------------------------#
        #Paramètres d"actifs et financiers#
        #---------------------------------#
        cr1 = leftjoin(cr1,tra,on = [:scn])           #TRA
        cr1 = leftjoin(cr1,ts,on = [:tab_ts])         #TS
        cr1 = leftjoin(cr1,ind_action,on = [:scn])    #Indice actions
        cr1 = leftjoin(cr1,df,on = [:scn])            #Discount Factor
        cr1 = leftjoin(cr1,tx_is,on = [:scn])         #Taux d"IS
        cr1 = leftjoin(cr1,inf,on = [:scn])           #Inflation


        ##CR deterministe sur duree de projection
        for i in 1:dur_proj
            #---------#
            ##Technique
            #---------#
            cr1[!,"ch_prime"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"ch_prime"].*(cr1[!,"coll_"*str(i)].*(cr1[!,"eu"]
            .+cr1[!,"uc"].+cr1[!,"ve"]).+cr1[!,"ca_prev"*str(i)])##chargements sur primes OK
            cr1[!,"dc"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"qx"*str(i)].*(cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i-1)].+cr1[!,"ca_prev"*str(i)])#deces OK
            cr1[!,"rach"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"lap"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i-1)].*(cr1[!,"eu"].+cr1[!,"uc"].+cr1[!,"ve"]) #Rachats structurels KO - Defo ancienneté avec collecte
            cr1[!,"eche"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"ech"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i-1)]#Echeances OK
            #cr1["arb"*str(i)]=cr1["sw"*str(i)]*cr1["pm_"+str(i-1)] #Arbitrages € vers UC KO lien produit multi
            cr1[!,"ch_enc"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"ch_enc"].*cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i-1)].+(cr1[!,"coll_"*str(i)]
            .-cr1[!,"rach"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"dc"*str(i)]).*((1 .+cr1[!,"ch_enc"]).^(0.5).- 1)#chargements sur encours OK
            #RT Prevoyance (intègre de fait les chargements sur primes => à oter du résultat ass)
            cr1[!,"rt"*str(i)].=(1 .-cr1[!,"SP"].-cr1[!,"ch_prime"]).*cr1[!,"ca_prev"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"prev"]

            #---------#
            ##Financier
            #---------#
            #IT#
            cr1[!,"IT"*str(i)].=(cr1[!,"eu"].+cr1[!,"ve"]).*(cr1[!,"IT"].*cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i-1)].+(cr1[!,"coll_"*str(i)]
            .-cr1[!,"rach"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"dc"*str(i)]).*((1 .+cr1[!,"IT"]).^(0.5).-1))#IT OK
            #PB distribuée
            cr1[!,"pb_dist"*str(i)].=(cr1[!,"eu"].+cr1[!,"ve"]).*((cr1[!,"ts"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"IT"]).*cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i-1)]
            .+(cr1[!,"coll_"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"rach"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"dc"*str(i)]).*((1 .+cr1[!,"ts"*str(i)]
            .-cr1[!,"IT"]).^(0.5).-1))#PB dist OK
            #Ajustements ACAV
            cr1[!,"acav"*str(i)].=(cr1[!,"uc"].*cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i-1)].*(cr1[!,"inda"*str(i+1)]./cr1[!,"inda"*str(i)].-1)
            .+(cr1[!,"coll_"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"ch_prime"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"rach"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"dc"*str(i)]).*cr1[!,"uc"]
            .*(cr1[!,"inda"*str(i+1)]./cr1[!,"inda"*str(i)].-1)./2)

            #Produits financiers contrats
            cr1[!,"pfi"*str(i)].=(cr1[!,"eu"].+cr1[!,"ve"]).*cr1[!,"tra"*str(i)].*(2 .*cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i-1)]
            .+cr1[!,"coll_"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"rach"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"dc"*str(i)])./2 #produits financiers par produits - hors PPB - hors FP

            #Produits financiers sur PPB <=> Au prorata pfi contrats euros(suffisant en vision marginale)
            cr1[!,"pfi_ppb"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"ppb"*str(i-1)].*cr1[!,"tra"*str(i)]

            #CSG
            cr1[!,"csg"*str(i)].=(cr1[!,"eu"].+cr1[!,"ve"]).*cr1[!,"csg"].*(cr1[!,"pb_dist"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"IT"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"ch_enc"*str(i)])

            ##PM fin
            cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i)].=(cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i-1)].+cr1[!,"coll_"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"ca_prev"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"ch_prime"*str(i)]
            .-cr1[!,"ch_enc"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"dc"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"rach"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"acav"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"eche"*str(i)]
            .+cr1[!,"IT"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"pb_dist"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"csg"*str(i)]).*(cr1[!,"eu"].+cr1[!,"ve"].+cr1[!,"uc"])

            #Retrocessions UC
            cr1[!,"retro"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"retro"].*(cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i-1)].+cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i)]).*0.5

            #Correctifs ratios de frais
            cr1[!,"cor_fg_uc0"].=1
            cr1[!,"cor_fg_eu0"].=1

            cr1[!,"cor_fg_uc"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"cor_fg_uc"*str(i-1)].*((cr1[!,"inf"*str(i-1)].+cr1[!,"der_fg"])
            ./(cr1[!,"inda"*str(i+1)]./cr1[!,"inda"*str(i)]))
            cr1[!,"cor_fg_eu"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"cor_fg_eu"*str(i-1)].*((cr1[!,"inf"*str(i-1)].+cr1[!,"der_fg"])
            ./(1 .+cr1[!,"ts"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"IT"]))

            #Frais généraux
            ##FG d"administration epargne
            cr1[!,"fg_ad"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"fga"*str(i)].*(cr1[!,"cor_fg_uc"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"uc"].+cr1[!,"cor_fg_eu"*str(i)]
            .*(cr1[!,"eu"].+cr1[!,"prev"].+cr1[!,"ve"])).*(cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i-1)].+cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i)].-(cr1[!,"IT"*str(i)]
            .+cr1[!,"pb_dist"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"csg"*str(i)]).*(cr1[!,"eu"].+cr1[!,"ve"]))./2
            ##FG d"aquisition
            cr1[!,"fg_acq"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"fgacq"*str(i)].*(cr1[!,"coll_"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"ca_prev"*str(i)])
            #FG Prestations
            cr1[!,"fg_prest"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"fgp"*str(i)].*(cr1[!,"cor_fg_uc"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"uc"].+cr1[!,"cor_fg_eu"*str(i)]
            .*(cr1[!,"eu"].+cr1[!,"prev"].+cr1[!,"ve"])).*(cr1[!,"rach"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"dc"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"ca_prev"*str(i)]
            .*cr1[!,"SP"])

            #Coms de gestion & admin (mma)
            cr1[!,"com_ad"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"com_ad"].*(cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i-1)].+cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i)].-(cr1[!,"IT"*str(i)]
            .+cr1[!,"pb_dist"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"csg"*str(i)]).*(cr1[!,"eu"].+cr1[!,"ve"]))./2#OK
            cr1[!,"com_acq"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"com_acq"].*cr1[!,"coll_"*str(i)]##=>OK

            #PB min
            #Solde souscription
            cr1[!,"ssous"*str(i)].=(cr1[!,"eu"].+cr1[!,"ve"].+cr1[!,"prev"]).*(cr1[!,"ch_enc"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"rt"*str(i)]
            .+cr1[!,"ch_prime"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"fg_ad"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"fg_acq"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"fg_prest"*str(i)]
            .-cr1[!,"com_ad"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"com_acq"*str(i)])

            #Determination composante technique (4,5% Pprev ou 10% tech)
            if tcomp_mod==1
                cr1[!,"tcomp"*str(i)].=tcomp_fixe
            elseif tcomp_mod==0 && sum(cr1[!,"ca_prev"*str(i)]).*0.045 .> sum(cr1[!,"ssous"*str(i)]).*0.1
                cr1[!,"tcomp"*str(i)].=1
            else
                cr1[!,"tcomp"*str(i)].=0
            end

            #Quid du changement de contrainte sur le technique en fonction des produits enlevés?
            cr1[!,"pb_min"*str(i)].=0.85.*(cr1[!,"pfi"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"pfi_ppb"*str(i)]).+(cr1[!,"ssous"*str(i)]
            .-cr1[!,"tcomp"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"ca_prev"*str(i)].*0.045) .-((1 .-cr1[!,"tcomp"*str(i)]).*cr1[!,"ssous"*str(i)].*0.10)

            #Variation de PPB par produit
            cr1[!,"varppb"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"pb_min"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"IT"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"pb_dist"*str(i)]

            #PPB par produit
            cr1[!,"ppb"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"ppb"*str(i-1)].+cr1[!,"varppb"*str(i)]

            #RT Vie entière
            cr1[!,"rtve"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"ve"].*(-1).*(cr1[!,"ch_enc"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"fg_ad"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"fg_prest"*str(i)]
            .-(cr1[!,"ca_prev"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"ch_prime"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"varppb"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"fg_ad"*str(i)]
            .-cr1[!,"fg_prest"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"dc"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"rach"*str(i)]))

            #PM finale yc RT Vie entière
            cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"rtve"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"varppb"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"ve"]

            #Impots
            cr1[!,"IS"*str(i)].=(cr1[!,"ch_prime"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"ch_enc"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"pfi"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"pfi_ppb"*str(i)]
            .-cr1[!,"pb_min"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"retro"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"rt"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"fg_ad"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"fg_acq"*str(i)]
            .-cr1[!,"fg_prest"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"com_ad"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"com_acq"*str(i)]).*cr1[!,"tx_is"*str(i)]

            #Résultat net Assurance apres IS
            cr1[!,"rnai"*str(i)].=(cr1[!,"ch_prime"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"ch_enc"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"pfi"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"pfi_ppb"*str(i)]
            .-cr1[!,"pb_min"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"retro"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"rt"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"fg_ad"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"fg_acq"*str(i)]
            .-cr1[!,"fg_prest"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"com_ad"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"com_acq"*str(i)]).*(1 .-cr1[!,"tx_is"*str(i)])

            #Profits futurs "actualisés (PVFP)
            cr1[!,"pvfp"*str(i)].=cr1[!,"rnai"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)]
        end


        #---------------------------------------------#
        #Variables d"intérêt actualisés sur duree proj
        #Principaux éléments de marge
        #---------------------------------------------#
        cr1[!,"ch_enc_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"ch_prime_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"pfnd_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"retro_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"rt_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"fg_ad_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"fg_acq_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"fg_prest_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"com_ad_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"com_acq_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"IS_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"pvfp_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"pm_actu"].=(cr1[!,"pm_0"].*cr1[!,"df1"].-cr1[!,"pm_"*str(dur_proj-2)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(dur_proj-1)])./2 #initialise
        cr1[!,"ca_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"pfi_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"pfi_ppb_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"pb_dist_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"IT_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"varppb_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"dc_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"rach_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"marge_sous_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"marge_acq_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"marge_ges_actu"].=0
        cr1[!,"marge_fi_actu"].=0


        for i in 1:dur_proj
           cr1[!,"ch_enc_actu"].=cr1[!,"ch_enc_actu"].+(cr1[!,"ch_enc"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)])
           cr1[!,"ch_prime_actu"].=cr1[!,"ch_prime_actu"].+(cr1[!,"ch_prime"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)])
           cr1[!,"pfnd_actu"].=cr1[!,"pfnd_actu"].+(cr1[!,"pfi"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"pfi_ppb"*str(i)].-cr1[!,"pb_min"*str(i)]).*cr1[!,"eu"].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)]
           cr1[!,"retro_actu"].=cr1[!,"retro_actu"].+cr1[!,"retro"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)]
           cr1[!,"rt_actu"].=cr1[!,"rt_actu"].+cr1[!,"rt"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)]
           cr1[!,"fg_ad_actu"].=cr1[!,"fg_ad_actu"].+cr1[!,"fg_ad"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)]
           cr1[!,"fg_acq_actu"].=cr1[!,"fg_acq_actu"].+cr1[!,"fg_acq"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)]
           cr1[!,"fg_prest_actu"].=cr1[!,"fg_prest_actu"].+cr1[!,"fg_prest"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)]
           cr1[!,"com_ad_actu"].=cr1[!,"com_ad_actu"].+cr1[!,"com_ad"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)]
           cr1[!,"com_acq_actu"].=cr1[!,"com_acq_actu"].+cr1[!,"com_acq"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)]
           cr1[!,"IS_actu"].=cr1[!,"IS_actu"].+(cr1[!,"IS"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)])
           cr1[!,"pvfp_actu"].=cr1[!,"pvfp_actu"].+cr1[!,"pvfp"*str(i)]#déjà actualisée
           cr1[!,"ca_actu"].=cr1[!,"ca_actu"].+(cr1[!,"ca_prev"*str(i)].+cr1[!,"coll_"*str(i)]).*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)]
           cr1[!,"pfi_actu"].=cr1[!,"pfi_actu"].+(cr1[!,"pfi"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)])
           cr1[!,"pfi_ppb_actu"].=cr1[!,"pfi_ppb_actu"].+(cr1[!,"pfi_ppb"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)])
           cr1[!,"pb_dist_actu"].=cr1[!,"pb_dist_actu"].+(cr1[!,"pb_dist"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)])
           cr1[!,"IT_actu"].=cr1[!,"IT_actu"].+(cr1[!,"IT"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)])
           cr1[!,"varppb_actu"].=cr1[!,"varppb_actu"].+(cr1[!,"varppb"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)])
           cr1[!,"dc_actu"].=cr1[!,"dc_actu"].+(cr1[!,"dc"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)])
           cr1[!,"rach_actu"].=cr1[!,"rach_actu"].+(cr1[!,"rach"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i)])
        end
        for i in 1:dur_proj-1
           cr1[!,"pm_actu"].=cr1[!,"pm_actu"].+(cr1[!,"pm_"*str(i)].*cr1[!,"df"*str(i+1)])
        end
        cr1[!,"marge_sous_actu"].=cr1[!,"rt_actu"]
        cr1[!,"marge_acq_actu"].=cr1[!,"ch_prime_actu"].-cr1[!,"com_acq_actu"].-cr1[!,"fg_acq_actu"]
        cr1[!,"marge_ges_actu"].=cr1[!,"ch_enc_actu"].+cr1[!,"retro_actu"].-cr1[!,"com_ad_actu"].-cr1[!,"fg_ad_actu"].-cr1[!,"fg_prest_actu"]
        cr1[!,"marge_fi_actu"].=cr1[!,"pfnd_actu"]

#        cr3 = cr1[:, All(Between(:gamme,:pm_0), Between(:ch_enc_actu,:marge_fi_actu))]

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do (not seeing the full code it is hard to write a full solution (also this will eat up a lot of memory, but again - in order to optimize this I would need to see the code; what I write has a benefit of being simple to implement and not require locking).

So the recommendation is:

1. create `cr2_vec = [copy(cr1) for i in 0:499]`
2. in outer loop write `cr2 = cr2_vec[k]`
3. Then do all the processing on `cr2`
4. after the `@threads` loop finishes take `cr2_vec`, which will have updated data frames and from each data frame of this vector take the columns that are needed and add it to your original `cr1` data frame.

A more advanced solution would be not to use a vector of data frames, but just a single data frame, as you do, but after the computing is done use a lock and within a lock update the global `cr1` with only the computed columns (you need to use lock to avoid race condition).

*EDIT*

An example of a more efficient implementation:

```
~$ JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4 julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.4.2 (2020-05-23)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> using DataFrames

julia> function example()
           df = DataFrame(id=1:10)
           tmp_df = df[!, :] # avoid copying columns, just copy the structure
           l = Threads.ReentrantLock()
           Threads.@threads for i in 1:500
               # avoid copying columns, just copy the structure; I assume that you do not modidy existing columns
               # if you do write copy(tmp_df) instead
               local_df = tmp_df[!, :]
               local_df.x = rand(nrow(local_df)) # here use any operations you want that add columns to local_df
               Threads.lock(l)
               # and here add new columns to df in a thread safe way
               # I have made just a simple example
               df[!, string("col", i)] = local_df.x
               Threads.unlock(l)
           end
           return df
       end
example (generic function with 1 method)

julia> example()
10×501 DataFrame. Omitted printing of 488 columns
│ Row │ id    │ col126    │ col127    │ col128    │ col1     │ col376     │ col251    │ col129    │ col377   │ col252   │ col378    │ col130    │ col253   │
│     │ Int64 │ Float64   │ Float64   │ Float64   │ Float64  │ Float64    │ Float64   │ Float64   │ Float64  │ Float64  │ Float64   │ Float64   │ Float64  │
├─────┼───────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┼────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 0.0859079 │ 0.196322  │ 0.419307  │ 0.692845 │ 0.0649538  │ 0.271088  │ 0.061715  │ 0.580881 │ 0.962198 │ 0.799577  │ 0.168915  │ 0.147532 │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 0.943435  │ 0.367186  │ 0.999753  │ 0.955678 │ 0.0250972  │ 0.960388  │ 0.0186629 │ 0.360238 │ 0.482318 │ 0.630828  │ 0.638949  │ 0.078192 │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 0.47552   │ 0.73942   │ 0.81966   │ 0.354086 │ 0.00347341 │ 0.889408  │ 0.836998  │ 0.46696  │ 0.467453 │ 0.939678  │ 0.211346  │ 0.28351  │
│ 4   │ 4     │ 0.802997  │ 0.761556  │ 0.848161  │ 0.893623 │ 0.651274   │ 0.564887  │ 0.248991  │ 0.667879 │ 0.644271 │ 0.25262   │ 0.246616  │ 0.759315 │
│ 5   │ 5     │ 0.252624  │ 0.452797  │ 0.925494  │ 0.986887 │ 0.125357   │ 0.593984  │ 0.030369  │ 0.607307 │ 0.572907 │ 0.496147  │ 0.512023  │ 0.166856 │
│ 6   │ 6     │ 0.538396  │ 0.225402  │ 0.800646  │ 0.296837 │ 0.74292    │ 0.327231  │ 0.210256  │ 0.60462  │ 0.611555 │ 0.0593179 │ 0.662082  │ 0.932477 │
│ 7   │ 7     │ 0.0371803 │ 0.7965    │ 0.0444999 │ 0.178894 │ 0.106347   │ 0.780827  │ 0.637981  │ 0.237108 │ 0.627657 │ 0.944787  │ 0.378639  │ 0.878564 │
│ 8   │ 8     │ 0.811234  │ 0.187935  │ 0.227647  │ 0.262164 │ 0.620936   │ 0.0184777 │ 0.438722  │ 0.38764  │ 0.125682 │ 0.194858  │ 0.490097  │ 0.958929 │
│ 9   │ 9     │ 0.540951  │ 0.0577447 │ 0.0718953 │ 0.316012 │ 0.670796   │ 0.867076  │ 0.0432124 │ 0.929919 │ 0.272197 │ 0.410973  │ 0.455775  │ 0.21984  │
│ 10  │ 10    │ 0.471401  │ 0.185443  │ 0.817339  │ 0.757105 │ 0.717144   │ 0.257629  │ 0.528992  │ 0.347383 │ 0.912039 │ 0.905729  │ 0.0434874 │ 0.75463  │
```

Note that in the result the order of columns will depend in what order the parallel threads run, so probably you will want to reorder the columns after this operation manually.

Comment: I tried this code (my understanding of you're answer)
"cr2_vec = [copy(cr1) for i in 0:499]

for k in 0:499
     cr2 = cr2_vec[k]
end
   #------------------------#
    #Boucle sur les scenarios#
    #------------------------#
    @threads for k in 0:499
        cr2[!,"scn"].=k   #scenario deterministe / parametrable en sto

        #---------------------------------#
        #Paramètres d"actifs et financiers#
        #---------------------------------#
        cr2 = leftjoin(cr2,tra,on = [:scn])"

Comment: I will update my answer with a simplified version of the code to show you how it should work.

Comment: Tks for you're time. I'm a very beginner and have some basic questions. 
I've added the full code it it could help.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: Thank you
I will test this on my code.
Is it mandatory to encapsule it in a function ?

Comment: This is a basic rule in Julia - if you want performance - use functions. I would recommend making it a habit. It probably would work without wrapping it in a function, but in global scope many things might not get compiled in an optimal way.

Comment: If you want more explanation and guidance you are welcome to ask on https://discourse.julialang.org/ as this is a better place for discussion than Q&A format on SO.

Comment: Ok. I've posted the issue on discourse.julialang.org.